# How to convert unsigned numbers from signed to unsigned(binary and hexadecimal)?

Tags: math, assembly, binary, hex

So i'm trying to learn assembly language from Randall Hyde's book : The art of assembly language, and i've finished learning the first chapter and now i'm trying to do the exercises.
And i have the following question : how can i convert a binary value (positive or negative)
into a hexadecimal value of the opposite sign.And yes i know how to represent numbers from 0 to 15 in binary and also that 10 is f and so on...
 The problem that i have is the following ..i am given this number : 1001 1001 and i have to convert it in the opposite value.So far i have used the two's complement and have obtained this :

```
1001 1001 ----->shifting bits -----> 0110 0110
                add 1         -----> 0110 0111
```

And i should've obtained the opposite of the first number.Instead,when i'm calculating the values of the results i get this:

```
1001 1001 = 2^0+2^3+2^4+2^7 = 1+8+16+128 = 153 (which in my opinion is fine...)
```

and after converting the number i get this:

```
0110 0111= 2^0+2^1+2^2+2^5+2^6 = 1+2+4+32+64 = -103
```

What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

Your terminology is a bit off. You want to flip the bits (which you did), not "shift" them (which is something you'll learn about later.

What makes you think you did anything wrong? The negative of a number `x` is another number `y` such that `x + y = 0`. Let's look at your two numbers and add them:

```
  1001 1001
+ 0110 0111
-----------
  1111 1112
          ^ oops, 2 should be 10, so record 0 and carry the 1

  1111 1110
+        10 
-----------
  1111 1120
         ^ oops, 2 should be 10, so record 0 and carry the 1
```

Can you see where this will end up once you continue to carry the 1?

The lesson to learn here is that in order to interpret a number, you need to know whether it is intended to be a signed number or not. If it is intended to be a signed number and the sign bit is set, then in order to convert it to human output you should first negate the number, so that it is positive, and output a negative sign and the positive number.

Comment: +1 for a really nice representation of binary addition!

Answer (score 0):

The "value" of the sign bit is -128. That's the trick.
(for unsigned values, the value of the MSB is naturally +128)

1001 1001 = -128 + 16+8+1 = -103  --> convert to absolute value by inverting bits
0110 0110 = 64+32 + 4+2 = 102 (and when you add 1, 0110 0111 == 103)

1001 1001 = 128 + 16 + 8 + 1 = 153 as unsigned.

EDIT: one more option:

|1001 1001| = 256 - (128+16+8+1) = 256-153 = 103

Comment: yes,but isn't the value of the sign bit (positive or negative) applied to the whole number ?

Comment: I don't know how one "applies" a sign bit. If one want's to know the value of a signed integer, it can be done by the easy way (considering the value of the sign bit as -2^(w-1), where w is the length of the word, or by inverting the bits, adding one, and then calculating the weighted sum with all-positive weights. But computers don't need to do that. They can add and subtract the binary values without any consideration of the sign bit and the interpretation is left to the programmer (well the CPU helps it by setting or clearing "negative" or "overflow" or "carry" bits.)

Comment: Oh yes, it *also* happens to be, that the absolute value of the signed number can be calculated as 256 - n, (n=153) in this case.